# how to add an array of objects in a fetch request

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to add a post request containing an array of objects and i'm stuck. Could you help me and guide me where my problem is?

[this is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoO6q.png)

[this is what i want to save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS72M.png)

Comment: An idea: paste your code as text inside code block?

Answer (score 0):

You should use either await or then if you want to use then you can do it like this

```js
fetch('you api', {
   method: 'POST',
   body: JSON.stringify({
     // here put data you want to send
   })
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => {
    // you can do what ever you want here
    console.log(json)
  }
)
```

Or if you want to use async-await use this

```js
const getData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('your api', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      // your data
    }),
  });

  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
  // do what ever you want here 

};
```